# Need to divide string by half. Insert another string between both sides

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
        Console.Write("Ievadiet pirma masiva izmeru: ");
        string[] izmers1 = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
        Console.Write("Ievadiet otra masiva izmeru: ");
        string[] izmers2 = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];

        for (int i = 0; i < izmers1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ievadiet 1.masiva {0} masiva vertibu: ", i + 1);
            izmers1[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < izmers2.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ievadiet 2.masiva {0} masiva vertibu: ", j + 1);
            izmers2[j] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < izmers1.Length; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1.masiva {0} vertiba ir {1}", k + 1, izmers1[k]);
        }


        for (int p = 0; p < izmers2.Length; p++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2.masiva {0} vertiba ir {1}", p + 1, izmers2[p]);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        string sum = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < izmers1.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += izmers1[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);


        Console.WriteLine(garums);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

So my program is askin for user to enter how much times it will ask for array value.
Then you enter your array's values.
Let's say the first array size is 4 and then second one is 4 too.
the values are q,w,e,r and T,Y,U,I

So what i need is that my final result looks like: qwTYUIer

Basically i tought maybe i could divide first array values by half to get qw and er. And then just input second arrays values. How can i do it? And is it good to do it like this?

Comment: Its much easier to do it using string functions instead of using an array. However, arrays have advanced methods - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do something simple as

```
        string s1 = string.Join("",izmers1); // "qwer";
        string s2 = string.Join("",izmers2); // "TYUI";
        string result = s1.Insert(s1.Length / 2, s2);
```

:)

Comment: string result = s1.Insert(s1.Length / 2, s2); can you explain me: how does it know that qw goes on the left side, then s2 in the middle and then er on the right side? ---------- edit: oh i think i understand. s1.length/2 is the index where to insert s2? right?

Comment: the string function Insert uses two parameters. Insert(int whereToInsert, string whatToInsert). The reason why the second text gets in the center is that by taking the length of the first string and divide it by two. We will get the insert point for the middle of the string. I hope this explained it.